# Firebase Realtime Database Timestamp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I'm trying to include a timestamp as I add messages to the Firebase Realtime Database. I have found many similar questions posted, but none of the proposed solutions are working. I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong before I attempt to add the timestamp, maybe my config or something.

Here is my configuration:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getDatabase, ref, push, set, onValue, query, orderByChild } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-database.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};
  
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);
```

And here is my code when I try to add a message to my `messages` collection:

```js
const messageListRef = ref(database, 'messages');
const newMessageRef = push(messageListRef);

set(newMessageRef, {
    'name': name.value,
    'message': message.value,
    'createdAt': firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```

The error I'm receiving it:

```
index.js:31 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

I have also tried:

- app.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
- database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

And many others that I can't remember.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, Firebase Web v9.0.0, as you are using here was released in Aug 2021. You should update it to v9.6.6 from Feb 2022. A simple way to find the latest version number to use for the CDN urls is to visit [`firebase` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase), note the version number on the right and throw it into the CDN url.

Answer (score 7):

In Firebase v9+, you need to use [`serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#servertimestamp):

```js
import { getDatabase, ref, push, set, onValue, query, orderByChild, serverTimestamp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-database.js";

/* ... */

set(newMessageRef, {
    'name': name.value,
    'message': message.value,
    'createdAt': serverTimestamp()
});
```